# How to see a printout at Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am new in Python and Jupyter. I used PyCharm more than Jupyter. Since Jupyter is more popular than PyCharm, I'd like switch to Jupyter. After installation, I tried some very simple statements like:

print("hello world")

The printout didn't show. I even tested it by removing one of the quotes: print("hello world) and then ran it. There was no feedback at all. Did I install Jupyter incorrectly? Cannot figure out what is going on. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can offer something to compare things to. If you are using JupyterLab, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyterlab) and press `launch binder`. A **temporary** session will spin up and you can open a new notebook and your code should work there. If you are using the classic Jupyter notebook interface, [click here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master?urlpath=/tree/). By comparing to one of those, it should help you tell what things should look like. I'm most interested in your kernel indicator. Sessions timeout after inactivity so save back to local often.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you select a kernel for your Jupyter.
at the top right you will see kernel, click and select python3 or whatever you want to use.

testing with `print("hello world")` should return `hello world`